# How to put first element in list to last place, python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and i want to know how can I put the first element of the list men to the last place, so i will get the smallest absolute difference between this two lists and remember it each time we put the first one in list men to the last place. I hope you understand the question.. 
list woman stays the same, I only want to change list men by putting the first element to the last place, and second element to the first place.
example -> men[172, 181, 166, 172, 174, 165, 169, 169, 185, 168] after the first change...

```
__author__ = 'Majky'
woman = [158, 166, 150, 158, 152, 160, 172, 159, 158, 162]
men =  [168, 172, 181, 166, 172, 174, 165, 169, 169, 185]
biggest_abs = 0
for x, y in zip(men, woman):
   print(x, y, abs(x-y))
    if biggest_abs < abs(x-y):
       biggest_abs = abs(x-y)



print("biggest_abs is ", najvecja_abs)
```

Comment: Try to simplify your code, add a code section with the expected result... I think the heading is not really what you want to do? It should also be a working code... variable names are mixed, indentations wrong.

Comment: You might want to look at using a `collections.deque` instead of a `list` and then calling `rotate(-1)` on it.

Comment: this code prints the biggest difference between lists. 31 is the largest diference.. i want to get the smallest difference possible

Comment: The code doesn't print anything. Copy and execute it... 185-158=35 is the largest difference?

Answer (score 7):

```
men = men[1:] + [men[0]]
```

Is what I would do. This slices the list such that you have everything but the first element, then adds that onto the end.

This returns `[172, 181, 166, 172, 174, 165, 169, 169, 185, 168]` when applied to the initial value of `men`, as an example.

Answer (score 6):

There's more than one way to do it... this one edits the list in place (meaning all references to the 'men' list see the change):

```
>>> men =  [168, 172, 181, 166, 172, 174, 165, 169, 169, 185]
>>> men.append(men.pop(0))
>>> men
[172, 181, 166, 172, 174, 165, 169, 169, 185, 168]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not clear now. May you wanna do a comparision of men values with each value of women.

```
for m in men:
    biggest_abs = 0
    for w in women:
        a = abs(m-w)
        if biggest_abs < a:
            biggest_abs = a
    print("biggest_abs is ", biggest_abs)
```

This will print intermediate steps:

```
('biggest_abs is ', 18)
('biggest_abs is ', 22)
('biggest_abs is ', 31)
('biggest_abs is ', 16)
('biggest_abs is ', 22)
('biggest_abs is ', 24)
('biggest_abs is ', 15)
('biggest_abs is ', 19)
('biggest_abs is ', 19)
('biggest_abs is ', 35)
```

Or an overall solution:

```
biggest_abs = 0
for m in men:
    for w in women:
        a = abs(m-w)
        if biggest_abs < a:
            biggest_abs = a
print("biggest_abs is ", biggest_abs)

('biggest_abs is ', 35)
```

For the smallest difference just switch geater to smaller than in the if condition and give the value a  meaningful name.